# Non heap memory and No of loaded classes keeps on increasing

Tags: java, performance, memory-leaks, profiling, jboss7.x

We are doing a performance test of our application.
During the test, we find that non heap memory and total no of loaded classes keeps on increasing over the time.

Our guess is probably some 3rd party jar or application code is leaking.

What are the best ways to find such leak or pin point the problem ?
Any tools which can help me to find the rootcause ?

We are using Jboss EAP 6.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make first Heap Dump by jvisualVm from JDK and analyze it with [Memory Analyzer (MAT)](https://www.eclipse.org/mat/).

And then see in this direction at header 'Non-Heap': [http://www.yourkit.com/](http://www.yourkit.com/docs/kb/sizes.jsp)

Comment: JConsole can also be used, which is a lower version of jvisulavm.

Comment: Learn More, I'm not sure it can create Heap Dump files.

Comment: @Dmitry will taking heap dump help as the issue is with non heap memory which is increasing ?

Comment: Yes, but JConsole will give a nice line graph for class loading and unloading one line represents total( including duplicates) and other  without duplicates.

Comment: Using yourkit I was able to find the classes which are getting created dynamnically...

Comment: Good news! Good luck!

Comment: If non heap keeps increasing, why a heap dump would help? The problem is not on the amount of memory consumed by the heap, is it?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like something in your code could be continually creating new dynamic proxy classes.  I think that that would give you a leak with the characteristics that you describe.

Other Q&A's explain general techniques for tracking down Java storage leaks; e.g.

- [How to find a Java Memory Leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40119/how-to-find-a-java-memory-leak)
- [Tracking down a memory leak / garbage-collection issue in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071631/tracking-down-a-memory-leak-garbage-collection-issue-in-java?rq=1)

I suggest you start by trying to identify the `Class` objects.  I suspect that you will find that the off-heap memory allocations are associated with them; e.g. associated native code segments produced by the JIT compiler.

Answer (score 0):

The JVM ships with a couple of tools that let you look at the contents of the heap ( jhat and  jmap ). Using these may allow you to see why you are seeing more than the expected number of loaded classes.

I'd start there before trying to see the non-heap memory usage.

Comment: I have been using tools like appdynamics,jconsole and I can say that heap doesnt seem to be an issue.heap utilization looks fine with proper GC cycles.thread count is also stable.Only thing which is a concern is of total no of classes loaded keeps on increasing which increases the non heap memory usage

Comment: Ok - we're getting passed my level of knowledge here, but where are these classes being loaded, if they aren't going on the heap?

Comment: classes are loaded in permgen space which is outside the heap

Comment: I think that's another argument - PermGen can just as easily be considered a special segment of the heap. jmap -permgen  will show you the contents of the permgen - that would still be the place I'd start.